# Recompile of class breaks (UTF-8) encoding

Tags: grails, groovy, utf-8

I've got a String that I encode as UTF-8 as so `new String("€#,##0.00\\ ".getBytes("UTF-8"), "UTF-8")`

When I run my code the first time everything works great and the string prints as `€#,##0.00\` but when I make a change and recompile the class it prints as `â‚¬#,##0.00\`

Comment: Which editor are you using? how are you compiling the class? which So are you using?

Comment: IntelliJ, just by hitting control +s, what do you mean so?

Comment: The source code is still "€" or change to "â"?

Comment: Source code is still €